# Should the html-parsing tags also be tagged as html

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

In Stack Overflow should questions tagged as [html-parsing](/questions/tagged/html-parsing) also be tagged as [html](/questions/tagged/html).

I believe NOT, because questions tagged [html](/questions/tagged/html) should be searched by people looking to find solutions for problems relating to html itself, for example:

1. [how to put image in center of html page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11206109/how-to-put-image-in-center-of-html-page)

However, questions like the following ones pertain to parsing an HTML document in a certain programming language:

1. [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-to-parse-and-process-html-with-php/3577654#3577654)
2. [Values of <td></td> is not returned using HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187346/values-of-td-td-is-not-returned-using-htmlunit)

These questions are in my view rightly not tagged as [html](/questions/tagged/html). However the following question was tagged as both a couple of days ago when I removed it:

1. [Regex to match 2 html tags in 1 HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4529851/regex-to-match-2-html-tags-in-1-html-file)

However, one of my former colleague disagrees with me on this. His point is that it is related to [html](/questions/tagged/html) also. He has 3 times as much reputation as mine, so I thought of putting this in front of the masters.

What is your view on this?

Comment: If you ask me, I'd be more concerned about [questions tagged \[regex\]\[html-parsing\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex+html-parsing) than questions tagged [html][html-parsing].

Comment: What's the harm?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The harm is with searchability OR in appropriate results appearing in searches. Its also that someone might have lost a lot of votes on a particular tag, when I removed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't remove people's tags if they are relevant.

If someone is asking about [html-parsing], and they add the [html] tag to it, the [html] tag is *relevant* (the question pertains to HTML).

We don't make people remove the [c#] tag if their question also has the [c#-4.0] tag, nor should we.  The [c#] tag is where we go for all things C#.

Comment: Though, there is a difference between the relationship between C# and C#4.0 tags and the relationship between the html and html-parsing tags. As in C#-4.0 is a subset of C#, but practically speaking html and html-parsing are closely related, or at least closer than C++ parsing and developing in C++. So, I take this answer.